# Creating user in Laravel 5

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5

So I am following this [angular/Laravel 5 tutorial](http://www.toptal.com/web/cookie-free-authentication-with-json-web-tokens-an-example-in-laravel-and-angularjs) using JSON web Tokens. I am running into an issue.

Here is how it says create a user:

```
Route::post('/signup', function () {
   $credentials = Input::only('email', 'password','name');

   try {
       $user = User::create($credentials);
   } catch (Exception $e) {
       return Response::json(['error' => 'User already exists.'], Illuminate\Http\Response::HTTP_CONFLICT);
   }

   $token = JWTAuth::fromUser($user);

   return Response::json(compact('token'));
});
```

The problem is, `User::create($credentials);` does not encrypt the password, meaning, logins will always fail. I found this out by using Laravel's default registration.

My question is, how do I create a new user that creates it the correct way?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to hash the password yourself using the [`Hash` helper class](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/hashing). Try this:

```
Route::post('/signup', function () {
   $credentials = Input::only('email', 'password','name');
   $credentials['password'] = Hash::make($credentials['password']);
   try {
       $user = User::create($credentials);
   } catch (Exception $e) {
       return Response::json(['error' => 'User already exists.'], Illuminate\Http\Response::HTTP_CONFLICT);
   }

   $token = JWTAuth::fromUser($user);

   return Response::json(compact('token'));
});
```